# How to add custom path for taxonomy term page

Tags: uri, taxonomy-terms

I need to give custom path for one of my taxonomy term page which will be redirected to view page.
Example:- I have view page called testimonial and in my taxonomy i have a term called user testimonials which should be redirected to testimonial view page once user click on the term.

I have tried [taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) but its custom path feature is no more available.
Any suggestion, how can i complete this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code that will allow you to redirect all taxonomy paths to a custom URL.

```
function sample_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['taxonomy_term']['uri callback'] = '_sample_taxonomy_term_uri';
}

function _sample_taxonomy_term_uri($term) {
  return array(
    'path' => 'path-to-your-view/' . $term->tid,
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module you can configure URL patterns for your taxonomies.

But I think you are describing a different scenario. You have just one term (testimonials) that you want to lead to a different page (a View). I don't think that the pattern you are following is correct for this requirement. You're trying to do something like categories in WordPress.

You'd probably be better off creating a new content type called "testimonials".

Is there a reason you're using a taxonomy to do this?